# import django_filters.rest_framework error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I'm getting error when try to use django rest framework filters by following [this tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#api-guide). The error appear when I try to import the library:

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
```

and the error message is

```
ImportError: No module named 'django_filters.rest_framework'
```

FYI I'm using these version of library:

```
Django==1.10.3
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-filter==0.11.0
djangorestframework==3.5.3
```

Thank you

Comment: have you pip install and add it to your settings?

Comment: yes of course I have install them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

django-filter added the `rest_framework` sub-package in the 0.15 [release](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/releases/tag/0.15.0). The problem is that your environment originally had 0.11 installed.

Comment: Any idea why I didn't get the latest version even after '''pip --upgrade'''? I only get the latest version after uninstall and reinstall the package.

Comment: You need to run `pip install --upgrade`, not `pip --upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

after doing

`import django_filters`

use `help(django_filters)`

you should see

```
PACKAGE CONTENTS
compat
conf
constants
exceptions
fields
filters
filterset
models
rest_framework (package)
utils
views
widgets
```

From this point, you can tell rest_framework is a package it self, so do

`from django_filters import rest_framework`

Comment: Surprisingly first time I ran `help(django_filters)` there is no rest_framework package in package content. After that I uninstall then reinstall django-filters, and now it's available & run well. Thank you.